# How do I revert this drop-down button to show my original icons?

Tags: unity, 16.04, indicator

This is what I see:

[picture of drop-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZZUq.jpg)

This just happened today. I want the icons to be on the actual menu without having to press this drop-down button.

Comment: If you right-click on the icon, can you set the preferences for that indicator? Cheers, Al

Comment: Unfortunately not. If you mean the arrow, when I right click or left click on it the drop-down appears as the picture shows.

Comment: You must have recently installed a top panel `indicator` applet that condenses your icon menus. Open the dash, type in `Startup Applications` and select it. Look at what is automatically starting for your account, and disable the indicator that puts up that icon menu. Let me know what you find. Cheers, Al

Comment: In terminal, type `dpkg -l *indicator* | grep -i ii`. Best to copy and right-click-paste this command into terminal. You must have recently installed one of these.

Comment: I looked at the startup applications as you said, but there was nothing that removed it. However I did figure it out just a minute ago. I unchecked "Show icon on system tray" in something called "IBus Preferences". Thank you for your help Al.

Comment: Where did you see that? Must not be Ubuntu then, but a variant, or an older version? Cheers, Al

Comment: I tried right-clicking the arrow like you said, but as I said, it didn't do anything. So I just went through and right clicked all of the items. the "EN" icon allowed me to right click to show a menu and then I clicked on preferences. That showed the IBus Preferences window. Apparently it can also be accessed with `ibus-setup` in the terminal

Comment: It's 16.04 acutually